# Failed to connect to api.telegram.org port 443: Connection refused

Tags: api, bots, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, php-telegram-bot

I have been having this problem for a few days My host doesn't connect to Telegram APIs

```
Failed to connect to api.telegram.org port 443: Connection refused
```

I couldn't restart it . Is my host banned?